# Linked Service between two or more datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

is possible to configure a linked service between 2 or more datafactory?

I red documentation but i didn't found it

Thanks

Comment: Per my experience, we can to do that and never heard such configuration. Just as I know, we could share the  Integration runtime between 2 or more Data Factory.

Comment: But with integration runtime i can connect 2 datafactory together? Is the same to have a linked service?

Comment: No, they are different. We still need create linked service in each Data Factory to connect to  the same op-premise source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, we can't do that and never heard such configuration.

Just as I know, we only could share the Integration runtime between 2 or more Data Factory.

But we still need to create the linked service to connect to the same on-premise data source through shared shared self-hosted integration runtime

In one word, it's impossible to configure a linked service between 2 or more Data Factory.

Comment: i understood. I simulate it and is as you wrote